# (Basics) goToPrev function according to goToNext?

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I'm using this script to navigate between anchors with a next and a previous button.

I have this goToNext function and I want the same script for the goToPrev function. I'm pretty sure it's really easy but I tried and can't work it out properly...

```
var max = 5;
function goToNext() {
    var hash = String(document.location.hash);
    if (hash && hash.indexOf(/box/)) {
        var newh = Number(hash.replace("#box",""));
        (newh > max-1) ? newh = 0 : void(null);
        document.location.hash = "#box" + String(newh+1); 
    } else {
        document.location.hash = "box1";        
    }
}
```

Box is the name of my anchors.
Thanks !

Comment: I completely forgot to mention I replaced the +1 by -1 and that it basically works, problem is in fact that it doesnt stop at zero and goes to negative. Tried adding a var min to see if it would work by any chance but it didnt...

Comment: max is the number anchors in the page

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"#box1"` instead of `"box1"`?

Comment: Yeah I guess, just changed it... Was working tho !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
function goBy( x ) {
    var hash, n;

    hash = location.hash;

    if ( hash.search( /^#box/ ) > -1 ) {
        n = +hash.slice( 4 ) + x;
        if ( n > max ) { n = 1; } else if ( n < 1 ) { n = max; }        
        location.hash = '#box' + n;
    } else {
        location.hash = '#box1';
    }
}
```

You use this function by invoking either `goBy(1)` or `goBy(-1)` (depending on which button was clicked).

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/4h6he/5/show/

**Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/4h6he/5/

Comment: @Moop I've updated the demo (to have `#box1` selected on page-load - I assume that's the desired behavior).

Comment: @Moop Depends on your HTML code. Do the anchors have a class set (in that case `max = document.querySelectorAll('.yourClass').length;`)? Are the anchors in a container element (in that case max is the number of children of that container: `max = container.children.length;`)?

Comment: Well this is how Ive done it... <a name="box1">&nbsp;</a>
I know it doesnt look too good but I'm not too good at this either ;)

Comment: @Moop The `name` attribute is not valid on anchors. Use the `id` attribute instead. Are those anchors inside some common container (e.g. a DIV)?

Comment: Thing is I need to put "position:relative; top:-61px;" because I have a fixed topbar (Live demo http://moopdesign.com/neworder/project.html) and I tried writting <div id="box1" style="position:relative; top:-61px;"></div> and it goes to the anchor but I don't get the 61 px offset !

Comment: And do you have any idea how to make a slide animation when going to the next anchor ?

Comment: @Moop Well, scroller scripts do that. If you use a library (like jQuery) there should be a plug-in for scrolling animations... (for instance: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ )

Comment: Cool man thanks for everything. You made things much easier ! Take care.

Comment: Hey man do you think theres an easy way to set a max to the anchors cause Ive been trying to work it out and its too much :/ I have to keep this <a name> form...

Comment: @Moop Try this: `var max = document.querySelectorAll( 'a[name^="box"]' ).length;`